# Write a java websocket client using Spring's SockJsClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a WebSocket server that written in Java and started without any problem. (on "ws" endpoint)

Simply,
I want to develop a client in below tasks :

1. create a connection to the server
2. subscribe to defined topics (e.g "topic/public")
3. Receive from response topic
4. Send to request topic

When I used Stomp as below it works well. but I couldn't do this way when I use StandardWebSocketClient.

```
    //Init
    WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);
    stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new CustomStompSessionHandler();

    //Connect
    StompSession stompSession = stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:8080/ws", sessionHandler).get();

    //Subscribe
    stompSession.subscribe("/topic/public", sessionHandler);

    //Send Message
    stompSession.send("/app/chat.addUser", new ChatMessage(MessageType.JOIN, "New User Added"));
    stompSession.send("/app/chat.sendMessage", new ChatMessage(MessageType.CHAT, "Test Message", "Test username"));
```

Now I want to do this with **SockJsClient**. it's pretty easy to handshake and create a connection but after that, how can I subscribe to the specific topic?

```
    //Init
    List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>(2);
    transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient()));
    transports.add(new RestTemplateXhrTransport());
    SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

    //Connect (Handshake)
    WebSocketSession webSocketSession = sockJsClient.doHandshake(new CustomWebSocketHandler(), "ws://localhost:8080/ws").get();

    //HOW CAN I SUBSCRIBE ?????

    //Send Message (To where? Which Path? Which topic)
    WebSocketMessage webSocketMessage = new TextMessage(new String("test Message").getBytes());
    webSocketSession.sendMessage(webSocketMessage);
```

> In BRIEF: HOW CAN I SUBSCRIBE TO SPECIFIC TOPIC WHEN I USE **SockJsClient**?

**To remind: Server was ok, and the other approach (StandardWebSocketClient) was working well.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement STOMP protocol from scratch then you need to [read specification](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#SUBSCRIBE) and construct your `SUBSCRIBE` and other commands by hand in text message body.

But you can initialize the same `WebSocketStompClient` with configured `SockJsClient` as `WebSocketClient` constructor argument like [this](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-stomp-websocket/blob/master/complete/src/test/java/hello/GreetingIntegrationTests.java#L52)

Comment: No, I don't need to implement it, I just wanna do some normal stuff like "subscribe" with SockJsClient as I did it with StandardWebSocketClient.

Comment: Both SockJsClient and StandardWebsocketClient are instances of WebSocketClient so you can just pass SockJsClient to WebSocketStompClient constructor, answer is updated.